# Why does the Ember mock server not run during acceptance tests?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have used the `ember generate http-mock foo` command to create a mock server in my Ember application.

However, the server is not started during acceptance tests when using the `ember test` command, even though it works in the development environment when using the `ember server` command.

Why is that? Does the server have to be manually started in each test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with those mocks that they don't work for acceptance tests. Look into using Ember-CLI-Mirage, that's one of the main reasons it was written.

Comment: That is what I was using originally, but I moved over to a mock server so that I could make use of the express.js middleware functionality. But yeah, generally, Mirage is the best thing to use, but it still needs a lot of work before it can completely replace http-mock.